# Where to find PySAL toolbox for ArcGIS?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, python, pysal

I installed PySAL but i can't find the toolbox for ArcGIS.

Answer (score 8):

pysal is a Python module, not an Esri product.  You'll have to write your own pySal tools and place them in a toolbox.

Comment: No longer the case; Xing Kang from ASU interned at Esri this summer and worked on integrating PySAL into ArcGIS. [There are now TBX files for PySAL tools, though they are apparently not yet online anywhere for download](https://geodacenter.asu.edu/arc_pysal_install). There is a powerpoint presentation on the PySAL web page that suggests they will be integrated in ArcGIS 11.

Comment: PySAL is now available as a toolbox for download on this page: https://geodacenter.asu.edu/software, see this download: https://geodacenter.org/downloads/unprotected/PySAL_ArcToolbox_v3.zip

Comment: @JasonScheirer The toolbox is not Esri, it's still 3rd party.  The question was specifically referencing a product.

Answer (score 1):

The most current version of this project is on github:

https://github.com/Esri/PySAL-ArcGIS-Toolbox

We are in the process of updating the install documentation and creating a homepage for the project.

Regarding installation... for all ArcGIS Pro Users, SciPy is already in the build.  Further, Conda is used as the Python Distro/Env for all Pro Versions 1.3 and beyond... so a simple 'conda install pysal' is the only command needed to get the cloned project to work.  For info on using Conda in ArcGIS Pro see: http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/arcpy/get-started/what-is-conda.htm

Conda is not used in ArcGIS Desktop (Classic).  For newer versions of Desktop (I think 10.4.1 and Beyond) SciPy is already in the install... so you just have to 'pip install pysal'.  For older versions you must use the Table in the current instructions to identify the correct Python/NumPy Combo to link with SciPy.  Again, see the doc and make sure you do not install the SciPy Stack which can override your NumPy version and break the ArcGIS DLLs (pyds).

Please check back with the github page in the coming weeks to see the updated installation instructions.  Hope this helps :-)

Answer (score 0):

You can find the **ArcGIS PySAL Tool** for **ArcGIS 10.1** available for download on this **[page](https://geodacenter.asu.edu/software)** where its functionality is described as:

> Spatial weights and regression PySAL tool for ArcGIS. Additional PySAL
>   functionality will be integrated with ArcGIS 11.